# AWS Aurora/Python: Connect to only write instance

Tags: amazon-web-services, sqlalchemy, amazon-aurora

I have a AWS Aurora (Postgres) setup with a primary write instance, and two read replica instances. I'm connecting the the database by using python like the following.

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
DATABASE_URL = 'postgresql://' + username + ":" + password + "@" + host + ":" + str(port) + "/" + database
engine = create_engine(DATABASE_URL, echo=DEBUG)
```

This setup from above does not guaranteed that I can connect to the write instance, and sometimes it connect to a read replica, which caused problem when I need to write something to the database.

My questions here is that how can I always connect to the write instance? 
Do I config on the AWS side, or inside the Python Code?

Answer (score 1):

AWS Aurora [exposes the following endpoints](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonRDS/latest/UserGuide/Aurora.Overview.html) that you would be able to use in the `host` value in your code:

> **Cluster endpoint**
>
> A cluster endpoint is an endpoint for an Aurora DB
>   cluster that connects to the current primary instance for that DB
>   cluster. Each Aurora DB cluster has a cluster endpoint and one primary
>   instance.
>
> **Reader endpoint**
>
> A reader endpoint is an endpoint for an Aurora DB
>   cluster that connects to one of the available Aurora Replicas for that
>   DB cluster. Each Aurora DB cluster has a reader endpoint. If there is
>   more than one Aurora Replica, the reader endpoint directs each
>   connection request to one of the Aurora Replicas.
>
> **Instance endpoint**
>
> An instance endpoint is an endpoint for a DB
>   instance in an Aurora DB cluster that connects to that specific DB
>   instance. Each DB instance in a DB cluster, regardless of instance
>   type, has its own unique instance endpoint. So, there is one instance
>   endpoint for the current primary instance of the DB cluster, and there
>   is one instance endpoint for each of the Aurora Replicas in the DB
>   cluster.

It's not entirely clear to me which endpoint you are currently using. The part of your code that obtains the `host` value, or the method you are using to set that value manually, is the only relevant part of your code in question, and you didn't include that. It sounds like perhaps you are using the Instance endpoint to point to the primary instance, but in the event of a failover that instance is becoming a read replica, which is causing your issue.

You should be using the Cluster endpoint, which will guarantee that your connections are going to the primary read/write instance.

Comment: If you are using the Cluster endpoint then you should not ever get a connection to a read-only instance. What is the actual error you are getting?

Comment: I'm getting: `ProgrammingError: (psycopg2.ProgrammingError) permission denied for relation trial`

Comment: FYI: Mark B's comment above is not correct. The cluster endpoint "...follows the primary instance in case of failover, that is, when the current primary
instance is demoted and one of the Aurora Replicas is promoted in its place."

Comment: @theannouncer please explain how my comment is incorrect. I think you are understanding the quote wrong. The cluster endpoint will always point to the current primary instance. If a primary instance is demoted, and a new one is promoted in it's place, then the cluster endpoint will stop pointing at the previous primary instance, and instead will point at the newly promoted instance.

Comment: Ah I see, you're correct, my bad. That is some ambiguous use of "follows" on the aws side, you are correct, my interpretation of the doc was "follows" as in "still points to the same thing" not "will always point to a writer" (for which I wouldn't use the word "follows"). Thanks for the clarification!

Answer (score 0):

Actual problem I overloaded the CPU, and DNS got re-configed. 
I need to increase the CPU and with some kind of limit control.